# How to make git switch to newly created branch automatically?

Tags: git, git-branch

```
1: git checkout master
2: git branch feature
3: git commit 'commit msg'
```

I am expecting git to switch branch on line 2 *(but it doesn't which is really annoying because I have to revert the check-in on master)*.

Is there any way to make git switch the branch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`git checkout -b yourBranchName` will do it for you

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git checkout -b`, which will checkout the newly created branch, i.e.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature
# work work work
git commit 'commit msg'
```

The commit will go into the new branch `feature` which was created from `master`.

Comment: Note also that you can combine the two steps as `git checkout -b feature master`, i.e., create and switch to `feature` while starting it off pointing to the same commit as `master`.

Comment: @torek As usual, your comments are more insightful than my answers.

Answer (score 3):

As you noted `git branch` just creates a new branch but does **not** switch over to it. Instead, you can use `git checkout -b feature` which both creates the new branch and switches over to it.

Comment: It's very unintuitive that `git branch` does not switch branches.

Comment: @kev: I agree. The set of things that `git checkout` and `git branch` do is quite non-intuitive. Of course, good user-oriented (as opposed to programmer-oriented) design people never let me get even the slightest bit close to doing design, so who am I to talk? :-)